# Next.js bundle size is exploding as a result of dynamic component lookup, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

## tldr:

Check the [repo](https://github.com/FBosler/fb-dynamicComponent) - common.js includes all dependencies, even though, only one is used on the respective page.

- http://localhost:3000/components/ComponentOne
- http://localhost:3000/components/ComponentTwo

**Livedemo: [click here](https://fb-dynamic-component.vercel.app/)**

## More Details:

I have an app (find attached a grossly simplified version) where based on a user input a different component is rendered. Finding the component to be rendered happens via a component-map.
It makes sense that the common.js includes all dependencies for the switcher page, where both components have to be accessible (and thus their dependencies).
But it does not make sense for the individual pages to include the respectively other dependency.

**To summarize:**

- I want to be able to have a large group of components, that can are rendered based on a user's input. It is not feasible for my use-case to serialize and deserialize ([as shown here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-render-a-component-dynamically-based-on-a-json-config)) them as the components are wildly different and require different dependencies
- I also want to render every component out to its own statically generated page, where I retrieve additional SEO information from a database. In this case, however, I only want to load the required dependencies for the particular component at hand.

### `http://localhost:3000`

[image]

### `Selecting ComponentOne results in:`

*Uses recharts.js*
[image]

### `Selecting ComponentTwo results in:`

*Uses victory.js*
[image]

Comment: @RandyCasburn thx! That helps a bit. Any idea how to achieve the same goal without being an outlaw?
In my actual app, I have thousands of components that can be inserted into a chat quite dynamically.

Comment: After scouring your code base again, I'm fairly certain my original assertion is wrong.

Comment: @RandyCasburn ya. I guess defining the componentMap the way I do kinda counts as top level.

Comment: Yep. It has to be related to the project structure - that I don't get.

Comment: Can you clarify how is the bundle size "exploding"? What differences are you seeing in the bundle size due to dynamic imports in your original app?

Comment: @juliomalves the Common.js is massive, as it includes every single dependency. I.e. page A also loads all dependencies for page B and every other page. It’s about 150kb extra.

Comment: @juliomalves also see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11082#discussioncomment-331254 pretty much the entire common.js is not needed for some of the pages.

Comment: @FabianBosler did you ever find a good solution to this issue? I too have a project w/ a map of dynamic imports and have the same problem of chunks being too big and containing largely irrelevant components.

Comment: @Sheraff yea, the suggested solution with the manual splitting did end up working as far as I remember

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### PROBLEM

TLDR: Next's Webpack configuration is chunking dynamically loaded components as its own chunk, which may create duplicated or combined chunk dependencies.

With your example, I duplicated component 1 and 2 as component 3 and 4 respectively. However, with component 4 (which is a copy of component 2), I added an additional `moment-timezone` dependency. The result is a separated chunk with duplicated `victory-pie` dependencies (it also imported **the entire library** for both `victory` and `moment-timezone` packages):
[image]

#### EXPLANATION

Even though there is quite a lot of dependency sharing between the two 3rd party charting packages (mainly both share `d3` dependencies), if the components are reusing 3rd party libraries that happen to have shared dependencies and be dynamically loaded across **multiple** routes, Webpack may attempt to combine these 3rd party chunks into one combined chunk:
[image]
instead of the expected two or more chunks:
[image]

But, as you'll notice in the chunk screenshot right above, even if the 3rd party packages aren't being reused/reimported across multiple routes, you **still** have duplicated dependencies (for example, both large peach and lime-green chunks in the screenshot above contain duplicated `d3-scale`, `d3-time`, `d3-path`, and so on dependency chunks).

Unfortunately, this is a necessary and expected behavior of a component being imported via `next/dynamic` (also applies to using Webpack's dynamic `import` statements) because it must traverse the **entire** dependency graph for each dynamically imported component and (potentially) add them as their own chunk -- in other words, in the case of a dynamic loaded component, Webpack doesn't know what component is being loaded during runtime, so it must create an entire chunk for it to be able to be loaded upon request (even if other components may share the same dependencies, it won't know). Not only that, since it doesn't know what's being imported/used within the dynamic component, it can't tree-shake dependencies! This, as a result, creates incredibly large and duplicated chunks as you add more dynamically loaded components.

#### SOLUTION

Unfortunately, there's really no fix. Even when I tried to manually separate and group these dependencies as their own separate chunks (to reduce redundancy/build size), the component would no longer render. Which makes sense, when each component is chunked in a way to be its own separate "app" within the main app.

In this case, the simplest solution would to be render a static image in lieu of a dynamically loaded React component (like a thumbnail for a video).

#### OTHER THOUGHTS

I took a look into Next's Webpack configuration and was able to make some progress. You can create your own webpack [splitChunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks) rules for Next to use, which will help reduce some chunk redundancy; but, even then, I was still getting duplicate chunks (derived mostly from `d3` shared dependencies). You can try it out. Definitely not for the faint of heart as you'll be chasing a rabbit down a dark hole and you won’t achieve chunk distribution perfection. That said, it does help reduce the build size...
[image]

Here's some prelimary work to use as a foundation for your `next.config.js` file:

***next.config.js***

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    /* adds client-side webpack optimization rules for splitting chunks during build-time */
    if (!isServer) {
      config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
        ...config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups,
        victory: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](victory-pie|victory-core|victory-pie\/es)[\\/]/,
          name: "victory",
          priority: 50,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        recharts: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](recharts|recharts-scale)[\\/]/,
          priority: 20,
          name: "recharts",
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        lodash: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](lodash)[\\/]/,
          name: "lodash",
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          priority: 40,
        },
      };
    }
    /* return new config to next */
    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: thx so much. I was afraid that was going to be the outcome. A real bummer, that kinda means I have to manually create thousands of components. The problem is that different components have different dependencies and the cool thing about them is the fact that they are interactive. So image wouldn't work either :/

Comment: Updated answer. See `other thoughts` section for more info.

Comment: thx so much. Will have to read up on this, but if I understand correctly I should be able to split chunks up quite nicely if they don't share a common dependency? The example at hand is actually not one I am facing in production, since I am only using one plotting library. The dependencies are rather independent from each other. Could you maybe in one or two sentences explain what the cachGroups are? Are those individual common.js chunks?

Comment: When building the app for production, Webpack attempts to group/split dependencies into shareable chunks. That way you have a smaller and more optimized build size. Instead, Webpack can’t automatically determine how to chunk these dependencies, so by using Next’s Webpack configuration in combination with custom rules, we can help Webpack optimize the production build. Take a look at the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) for more information.