# Lazy loading component logic decreases lighthouse performance

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, lazy-loading, lighthouse

TL;DR: using Next.js `dynamic` imports to lazy-load user-interaction code results in decreased bundle size but *decreased performance*. Why?

---

Say I have a React component with some "logic" (state / effect / ref...) that looks like this:

```
// index.jsx
export default function Component({a, b}) {
  const someRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
  }, [a])
  return (
    <>{/* ... */}</>
  )
}
```

Hoping to minimize bundle size and initial code parsing / eval / exec, I'm trying to use Next.js `dynamic` to split the component into logic and markup. For example, if I have a slideshow, I want the markup to always be returned so I get a normal HTML, but for user interactions, we can wait until the slideshow is in the viewport (or some other condition).

1. This first function is reusable for any component that might wants to use this lazy-loading principle. It allows us to pass props to the `loading` component from `next/dynamic`:

```
// utils/dynamicWithLoader.js
export default function dynamicWithLoader(getDynamicComponent) {
    const Context = createContext({})
    const getProps = () => useContext(Context)
    const DynamicComponent = getDynamicComponent(getProps)

    return function DynamicWithProps(props) {
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={props}>
                <DynamicComponent {...props} />
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

2. This is the `index` of the component. Use `next/dynamic` to load the logic, and in the meanwhile, just return the markup without the logic.

```
// index.jsx
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import dynamicWithLoader from 'utils/dynamicWithLoader'
import PureMarkup from './PureMarkup'

const LazyLoaded = dynamicWithLoader((getProps) => dynamic(
  () => import('./Controller'),
  {
    loading: () => <PureMarkup {...getProps()} />,
    ssr: false,
  }
))

export default function LoadToggle(props) {
  return props.openPopin
    ? <LazyLoaded {...props} /> 
    : <PureMarkup {...props} />
}
```

3. This is the "pure" component, no hook or effect or anything, just JSX and CSS. That way there is zero content shift, no flash of content, or anything.

```
// PureMarkup.jsx
export default function Component({b, someRef}) {
  return (
    <>{/* ... */}</>
  )
}
```

4. This is the lazy loaded part of the component. It includes everything that is needed to make the component "work" but nothing that is necessary for its initial render.

```
// Controller.jsx
import PureMarkup from './PureMarkup'
export default function ComponentWithHooks({a, b}) {
  const someRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
  }, [a])
  return <PureMarkup a={a} b={b} someRef={someRef} />
}
```

I've tried to simplify a few things for the sake of example, but I can go more into it if needed. The point is: it works! It lazy loads the logic and the initial render is still correct, perfect.

**The problem is** that this seems to lead to a *decrease* in performance... I've tried applying this logic to as many components as possible inside a single web page (to make the overhead "worth it") and ran multiple lighthouse tests:

- the initial bundle size decreases (good)
- the performance score decreases (bad)

For the tests, I've ran 100 instances of puppeteer (in sequence, not at the same time) with a random order between "unmodified" and "with lazy loading" and did a lighthouse performance audit (simulated 3G mobile) each time. I did not program any "user interaction" in puppeteer, so the "lazy loaded" parts of the components were *never loaded during these tests*. And yet, the results indicate a decrease in performance

- Average score: 72.2 for "unmodified", 68.72 for "with lazy loading"
- Standard dev: 4.69 for "unmodified", 3.50 for "with lazy loading"

What could be the reason for decreased performance when there is less code to download and execute? Is `next/dynamic` that bad on CPU? What could I test / try to lazy load unnecessary code that wouldn't decrease perf?

Comment: When lazy loading/dynamic importing, I found the opposite to be true about bundle sizes: [Next.js bundle size is exploding as a result of dynamic component lookup, how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014730/next-js-bundle-size-is-exploding-as-a-result-of-dynamic-component-lookup-how-to/66085767#66085767)

Comment: Read this: https://thekevinwang.com/2021/03/15/reduce-first-load-js/#so-should-i-dynamically-import-everything

Comment: @MattCarlotta yes I have observed that, but for "later" chunks, not for the ones initially loaded (which is what I care about in this question). Depending on your components (not too many dependencies) you can try [webpack magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) to "help" it make the right chunks (I used `webpackChunkName` and `webpackMode`). Did you observe the initial bundle size increasing too?

Comment: @brc-dd ah ah! well the conclusion of this article is basically what I'm trying to do. Lazy-load all the things that will only be needed "later" (and load them *when they are needed*, not just "after the rest but still on page load") and nothing more. But somehow, I still get decreased performance... Even though bundle size is smaller, there aren't more requests (except later, on user interaction), but there is a bit of overhead as seen in the `dynamicWithLoader` function in my question. Maybe it's the react context that's CPU heavy? Or next/dynamic itself when used repeatedly?

Comment: BTW, I don't have the exact number on hand, but approximately, for 1k shaved off of the initial bundle, I get a 2k chunk to load later. So there is definitely a tradeoff between fast / light initial load and total amount of data over the lifetime of the page.

Comment: @Sheraff Have you tried checking your lighthouse score on [web.dev/measure](https://web.dev/measure/) or [pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) instead of your local setup? Also, can you show us the fields where you are getting difference in the lighthouse reports?

Comment: @brc-dd well this is a "rogue operation" I'm unofficially doing for the website of a client. All the dev environments are closed except for specific IPs. I have tested with builds deployed on a server w/ a similar infrastructure to that of the production site, but I can't really test with a third party service unless I want to lose my job. As for the fields: I only did average and deviation on the overall performance score, but IIRC the category that increased was Total Blocking Time.

Comment: Without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), my guess is that you're deoptimizing your shared chunk by creating one or more additional larger chunks, possibly with duplicate dependencies, that are being requested on initial load anyway. So instead of making one optimized request, you're making two (or more) requests for the same initial load. Check the `stat` size of your builds using the [bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer).

Comment: @MattCarlotta yeah reproducing it isn't going to be possible in this case, sorry (and I know, questions without reproduction tend to suck)... I'll update the post with stats from the bundle analyzer in a couple days, it's already setup but I can't access it on the weekends. But I did look at the network tabs of the chrome devtools and saw *as many requests* during initial load, *and smaller total download size* as well (about 60ko saved out of 500ko, non gzipped).